# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS with multiple queries

Tags: sql-server

| StudentId | StuName | School Fee Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | s1 | 10000 |
| 2 | s2 | 40000 |
| 3 | s1 | 20000 |
| 4 | s4 | 10000 |
| 30,22,48,60 | s6,s8,s9,s10 | 3300 |
| 8 | s12 | 1200 |
| 10 | s4 | 5000 |
| 12 | s16 | 4000 |
| 18,16 | s20,s21 | 10000 |
| 20 | s2 | 40000 |
| 22 | s6 | 30000 |

Table 2

| StudentId | StuName | Tution Fee Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | s66 | 10000 |
| 27 | s27 | 40000 |
| 3 | s3 | 20000 |
| 54 | s4 | 10000 |
| 30,22,48,60 | s6,s8,s9,s10 | 3300 |
| 8 | s12 | 1200 |
| 40 | s14 | 5000 |
| 12 | s16 | 4000 |
| 18,16 | s20,s21 | 10000 |
| 20 | s20 | 40000 |
| 25 | s25 | 30000 |

Expected Output

|  | SchoolfeePaid | Tutionfeepaid | Count3 | Count4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student1 | 10000 | 7000 | 4 | 2 |
| Student2 | 40000 | 10000 | 3 | 5 |
| Student3 | 70000 | 6000 | 4 | 3 |
| Student4 | 80000 | 4000 | 2 | 1 |
| Student5 | 5000 | 9000 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: This is the wrong way to write your query. But the error is plain: only return a single column. The next problem is when you try to shove multiple rows into a single scalar output.

Comment: If you provide consumable sample data, for your expected results, that will help us help you.

Comment: Presumably you need to join all the tables on id. You'll use case expressions to tally the summaries.

Comment: Are you the same guy who asked about hospitals a few questions back? This looks very similar

Comment: @UserNewman if you provide easily reproducible example DDL/DML you'll likely have better luck getting a response. You can do this like so: `DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Column1 INT, Column2 NVARCHAR(30)...); INSERT INTO @Table1 (Column1, Column2...) VALUES (1, 'String'...), (2, 'String'...)...;`

Comment: The `INSERT` is to produce the example data... You can see @siggemannen's answer for a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic concept you can use, since you didn't bother putting any sample data, i just did some mockups:

```sql
-- 1. Create some sample data
create table #table1 (id int, name varchar(30), fee numeric(19,12), date1 date, date2 date)
create table #table2 (id int, name varchar(30), fee numeric(19,12), date1 date, date2 date)
create table #table3 (id int, name varchar(30), fee numeric(19,12), date1 date, date2 date)
create table #table4 (id int, name varchar(30), fee numeric(19,12), date1 date, date2 date)

insert into #table1 (id, name, fee, date1, date2)
output inserted.id, inserted.name, inserted.fee + 10, inserted.date1, inserted.date2 into #table2
values  (1,'Test', 10, '20200101', '20200131')
,   (2,'Test2', 11, '20200101', '20200131')
,   (3,'Test3', 12, '20200101', '20200131')
,   (4,'Test4', 13, '20200101', '20200131')

insert into #table3 (id, name, fee, date1, date2)
output  inserted.id, inserted.name, inserted.fee + 30, inserted.date1, inserted.date2 into #table4
select  id, name, fee + 20, date1, date2
from    #table1

-- 2. Generate data
select id, name
,   max(case when counter = 1 then fees end) AS counter1
,   max(case when counter = 2 then fees end) AS counter2
,   max(case when counter = 3 then fees end) AS counter3
,   max(case when counter = 4 then fees end) AS counter4
from (
    select id, name, SUM(fee) as fees, 1 AS counter
    FROM #table1
    --where some condition
    group by id, name
    union all
    select id, name, SUM(fee) as fees, 2 AS counter
    FROM #table2
    --where some condition
    group by id, name
    union all
    select id, name, SUM(fee) as fees, 3 AS counter
    FROM #table3
    --where some condition
    group by id, name
    union all
    select id, name, SUM(fee) as fees, 4 AS counter
    FROM #table4
    --where some condition
    group by id, name
    ) x
group by id, name
```

Basically, you do a union all to get all the data into same kind of format of Id, Name, Count, and an identifier i called counter, this is to keep track what you're calculating.

Then you do a pivot so every counter gets it's own column, and you're done

Comment: think about it, i think you can figure it out

Comment: post your whole query in fiddle, maybe we can figure it out